# TVP-VAR fails statespace.MLEModel

Tags: python, statsmodels, state-space-models, linear-dynamical-system, nonlinear-dynamical-system

I am trying to run a TVP-VAR  for a panel in python using statsmodels. I am using the site example, trying to adopt it in my model. Data are from 1945-2020 for 50 countries Furthermore, I am getting an error primary in setting the self. In the class definition.

```
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined,
```

I have seen the previous answer by @cfulton) https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11974/cfulton here
[initial conditions for statespace mlemodel in statsmodel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514668/initial-conditions-for-statespace-mlemodel-in-statsmodel)

I have the following issues in my code that need to be taken carried.

I've reached up to this self['design'] part of the code, where it fails,
and I am unable to produce.

Could anyone help me here?

Here is some code of what I have run.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
 
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.tools import (
    constrain_stationary_univariate,
    unconstrain_stationary_univariate)

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace import initialization

# Get the macro dataset- import stata dta file
import pyreadstat
dtafile = 'TVP.dta'
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta(dtafile)
df.tail()
reader = pd.io.stata.StataReader('TVP.dta')
header = reader.variable_labels()
for var in header:
    name = var
    label = header[name]
   #  Panel data settings 
year = df.year
df['year'] = year.astype(int)

   
# Subset to the variables of interest
y = df[['gdp', 'prices', 'u', 'trade', 'labor', 'debt', 'exr']].copy()
y.columns = ['gdp', 'prices', 'u', 'trade', 'labor', 'debt', 'exr']



# 1. Create a new TVPPANELVAR class as a subclass of sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel
class TVPPANELVAR(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    # Steps 2-3 are best done in the class "constructor", i.e. the __init__ method
    def __init__(self, y):


 # Create a matrix with [y_t' : y_{t-1}'] for t = 2, ..., T
augmented = sm.tsa.lagmat(y, 1, trim='both', original='in', use_pandas=True)
        # Separate into y_t and z_t = [1 : y_{t-1}']
p = y.shape[1]
y_t = augmented.iloc[:, :p]
z_t = sm.add_constant(augmented.iloc[:, p:])

        # Recall that the length of the state vector is p * (p + 1)
  k_states = p * (p + 1)
  
  

 super(TVPPANELVAR).__init__(y_t, exog=z_t, k_states=k_states)
```

I've reached the code up to that point ,which sometimes even fails. When I try to set up the self['design']
I get self is not defined. Don't know what is wrong and w to solve it.

Need to mention that I do have missing data in the dataset . Impulse response function at the end of the code must be included.

Any help is appreciated