# Fitting TVP-VAR statespace mlemodel in statsmodel

Tags: time-series, python, vector-autoregression, statsmodels, state-space-models

1

Thanks to everyone in advance for their time!

I am trying to run a TVP-VAR for a panel in the statespace mlemodels in statsmodel. I get an error while trying to fit the model

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'


File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 113, in _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting
    return ufunc(*args, out=out, **kwargs)
```

The code I am running is

```
class TVPVAR(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    

    def start_params(self):
       
        start_params =  [.1, .1, 100, 100, 100]
        
    
    def __init__(self, y):
        # Create a matrix with [y_t' : y_{t-1}'] for t = 2, ..., T
        augmented = sm.tsa.lagmat(y, 1, trim='both', original='in', use_pandas=True)
        # Separate into y_t and z_t = [1 : y_{t-1}']
      
        p = y.shape[1]
        y_t = augmented.iloc[:, :p]
        z_t = sm.add_constant(augmented.iloc[:, p:])
        nobs = y.shape[0]
        T=y.shape[0]
         
        # Recall that the length of the state vector is p * (p + 1)
        k_states = p * (p + 1)
        super(TVPVAR,self).__init__(y_t, exog=None, k_states=k_states,k_posdef=k_states)
    
        
        self.k_y = p
        self.k_states = p * (p + 1)  
        self.nobs = T  
        self['design'] = np.zeros((self.k_y, self.k_states, 1))  
        
        self['transition'] = np.eye(k_states) # G
        self['selection'] = np.eye(k_states) # R=1
        
     
        
    def update_variances(self, obs_cov, state_cov_diag):
        self['obs_cov'] = obs_cov
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag(state_cov_diag)    # W
        init = initialization.Initialization(self.k_states)
        init.set((0, 2), 'diffuse')
        init.set((2, 4), 'stationary')
        self.ssm.initialize(init)
        
  
   
    def constrain_stationary_multivariate(unconstrained, variance,
                                      transform_variance=False,
                                      prefix=None):
      
        
      unconstrained = np.array(k_y * k_y * order)
      variance=np.array(k_y * k_y)
       
      order  = k_y
      
      prefix = find_best_blas_type(
            [unconstrained, variance])
      dtype = prefix_dtype_map[prefix]

      unconstrained = np.asfortranarray(unconstrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.asfortranarray(variance, dtype=dtype)
      # Step 1: convert from arbitrary matrices to those with singular values
      # less than one.
      # sv_constrained = _constrain_sv_less_than_one(unconstrained, order,
      #                                              k_y, prefix)

      sv_constrained = prefix_sv_map[prefix](unconstrained, order, k_y)
      # Step 2: convert matrices from our "partial autocorrelation matrix"
      # space (matrices with singular values less than one) to the space of
      # stationary coefficient matrices
      constrained, variance = prefix_pacf_map[prefix](
        sv_constrained, variance, transform_variance, order, k_y)

      constrained = np.array(constrained, dtype=dtype)
      variance = np.array(variance, dtype=dtype)

      return constrained, variance
      
   
    def unconstrain_stationary_multivariate(constrained, error_variance):
       
       constrained= np.array(k_y * k_y * order)
       error_variance=np.array(k_y * k_y)
       # Step 1: convert matrices from the space of stationary
    # coefficient matrices to our "partial autocorrelation matrix" space
    # (matrices with singular values less than one)
       partial_autocorrelations = _compute_multivariate_pacf_from_coefficients(
        constrained, error_variance, order, k_y)
       unconstrained = _unconstrain_sv_less_than_one(
        partial_autocorrelations, order, k_y)
       return unconstrained, error_variance
      
     

    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
        self['transition', 2,2] = params[0]
        self['transition', 3,2] = params[1]
        self['state_cov'] = np.diag([params[2]**2, params[3]**2, params[4]**2])  # W
    
    @property
    def state_names(self):
        state_names = np.empty((self.k_y, self.k_y + 1), dtype=object)
        for i in range(self.k_y):
            endog_name = self.y__names[i]
            state_names[i] = (
                ['intercept.%s' % y_name] +
                ['L1.%s->%s' % (other_name, y_name) for other_name in self.y_names])
        return state_names.ravel().tolist()
    
    
tvppanelvarmodel = TVPVAR(y)
index=year

preliminary = tvppanelvarmodel.fit(maxiter=1000)



res = tvppanelvarmodel.fit(preliminary.params, method='nm', disp=0, maxiter=1000) 
print(res.summary())
```

I have seen the previous answer by Chad Fulton(@cfulton) on the [initial conditions for statespace mlemodel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514668/initial-conditions-for-statespace-mlemodel-in-statsmodel)

Why is it so? Is there a way to understand the reason of these and advice on how to set it up.

Comment: I have forgoten to my code to include Ipulse response functiion. The code should read as :
# Impluse Response 
`code` ax = res.impulse_responses(10, orthogonalized=True, impulse=[1, 0]).plot(figsize=(13,3))
ax.set(xlabel='t', title='Responses to a shock to `xxxx`'); `code`